# CSS works locally but not on online server

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `Twitter Bootstrap` and made some changes to the navigation bar and the width of my content area through my custom stylesheet offline. Everything looked good locally.

But then I uploaded everything to the server and my new CSS rules are not applying. I opened the editor on the stylesheet on the server just to make sure that the changes I made were uploaded.

My style sheet IS there and is working except for the new rules.

Why aren't my new rules being applied?

Comment: Could be many reasons, so we'll need more information. First and foremost, try pressing "ctrl + F5".

Comment: Sounds like your browser has cached your CSS, so I would try clearing your cache in your browser. Additionally, in chrome, you can configure the web inspector to disable the cache when the web inspector is opened.

Comment: Or could be the hosting itself. I've had a few similar problems in the past with cheap shared hosting. It would have shown be the first change made but after that it took some time to display the rest of the changes. Dunno why.

Comment: Forgot to add that I cleared the cache and viewed it in several browsers. No luck.
@designarti The hosting is a cheap shared plan on GoDaddy(not my choice)

Comment: Can you provide a link and the identifiers/selectors for the rules that aren't being applied?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a number of things and without seeing your code it is hard to say. Check a few things. 1. that there aren't extra spaces between your rules (for example width: 50 px; ...there shouldn't be a space between the 50 and the px.....Also make sure that if you have div class="oneTwo" that you get the capitalization correct...sometimes locally these types of things are very forgiving of mistakes...

Have you tried deleting the already existing files on your server then uploading fresh (instead of just replacing them)

designarti has a point (has happened to me) where I've uploaded something and the old rules still apply but maybe 30 minutes later they kick in (especially on mobile)

Best bet would be to post your code so people here can see if there is a mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can use F12 debugger to pin point the applied style sheet of particular element. For situation like this you can not just rely on one browser. Switch between various IE, FF, Chrome,  some of them are more useful in particular situations.

Also try FirFox FireBug and FireFox Web Developer. We with Web Developer, you edit css live which can be useful.